# c#: use current credentials for api that uses basic authentication

Tags: c#, .net-core, basic-authentication

I have an c# .net 5 app running as a scheduled task on a server. The scheduled task runs with a user, that has privileges to access an api. The API uses basic authentication, but I can't figure out how to use basic auth, without sending the encoded user/pwd in the AuthenticationHeader. How is it possible to use the default credentials? I tried this out, but get access denied

```
   HttpClientHandler handler = new();
   handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic");
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "some uri");
```

Comment: That's how basic authentication works. What do you mean default credentials? Do you mean to use Windows Authentication that is built in to all (most?) browsers?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.credentials — set the Credentials to use, there is likely no need to play with auth headers (the server should send a challenge). It is not possible to use basic auth without sending such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if API uses Basic Auth you need to send the usr/pwd over, no workaround

> The Basic authentication scheme is a widely used, industry-standard
> method for collecting user name and password information. Basic
> authentication transmits user names and passwords across the network
> in an unencrypted form. You can use SSL encryption in combination with
> Basic authentication to help secure user account information
> transmitted across the Internet or a corporate network.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/basicauthentication

You need to change the API auth method to achieve what you want (read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/#how-to-enable-windows-authentication-for-a-web-site-web-application-or-web-service) on the same documentation)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the API. I was merely looking for a way to avoid putting in username/password, but I couldn't find a way to avoid it. Your answers confirms this. Thx!